# How to use Audio Profiles in Cocos2d Ver 3.3 AudioEngine

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, audio

I have 2 audio files that I want to play at different times: background.wav a sneeze.wav.  I believe that I have to convert both wav files into mp3, caf and ogg files.  Then I do this:

```
static const int FILE_COUNT = 2;
std::string _audioBackgroundFiles[FILE_COUNT];
_audioBackgroundFiles[0] = "background.mp3";
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS || CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_MAC
    _audioBackgroundFiles[1] = "background.caf";
#else
    _audioBackgroundFiles[1] = "background.ogg";
#endif

for(int index = 0; index < FILE_COUNT; ++index){
        auto id = AudioEngine::play2d(_files[index], false, 1.0f, &_audioProfile);
}
```

I don't understand how to create an audio profile?  Do you create a profile for every sound?  I'm very confused.

Comment: similar issue here with v3.10, I didn't bother to search for a solution because AudioEngine is still in it's experimental phase

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
#include "audio/include/AudioEngine.h"

using namespace cocos2d::experimental;

[...]

_musicVol = 5;
_backgroundAudioProfile = AudioEngine::INVAILD_AUDIO_ID;

if (_backgroundAudioProfile == AudioEngine::INVAILD_AUDIO_ID) {
    _backgroundAudioProfile = AudioEngine::play2d("background.mp3", true, _musicVol);
}

AudioEngine::pause(_backgroundAudioProfile);
```